# How do I hide and show some buttons?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

on markup page, we have these buttons hidden:

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="searchBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search Site" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="checkall" Text="Check All" OnClick="checkall_Click" /> 
   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uncheckall" Text="Uncheck All" OnClick="uncheckall_Click" />
```

Our desire is that on page load, hide the checkall and uncheckall buttons.

If the search button is clicked, then make the checkall and uncheckall buttons visible.

So far, my effort isn't working well.

First on page_load(...) event, I have these:

```
'make them hidden by default
checkall.Visible = False
unckeckall.Visible = False
```

Then on btnSearch_click (...) event, I want to make sure that search button is clicked and then make checkall and uncheckall buttons visible.

```
    If (btnSearch.ID = "btnSearch") Then
        checkall.Visible = True
        unckeckall.Visible = True
    End If
```

So far, it isn't working well.

On page load, the checkall and uncheckall buttons are hidden, just like we want.

When a user clicks Search Site, they are visible. That's good too.

Problem is when I click on checkall to check the checkboxes, the checkall/uncheckall buttons disappear again.

We only want them invisible when search sit button is not clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using the assignment operator (`=`) instead of the equality comparison operator (`==`) in your `if` statement.

Comment: Look more like your are using VB.NET instead of C#. Maybe edit your tags?

Comment: @gilly3: He's using VB.Net, not C#. VB.Net only uses a single = for equality comparison.

Comment: @rossisdead - Got it.  I was thrown off by the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your initializing code inside a `!IsPostBack` check:

```csharp
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    checkall.Visible = False;
    unckeckall.Visible = False;
}
```

Better yet, remove it from the C# make it declarative:

```xml
<asp:Checkbox ID="checkall" Visible="False" ... />
```

---

**Edit:**  Or, in VB:

```vb
If Not IsPostBack Then
    checkall.Visible = False
    unckeckall.Visible = False
End If
```

Right?  My VB may be a little rusty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
'VB
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

    'make them hidden by default
    checkall.Visible = False
    unckeckall.Visible = False

End If

//C#
If (!Page.IsPostBack) 
{

    'make them hidden by default
    checkall.Visible = false;
    unckeckall.Visible = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the OnClick event for btnSearch like below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="searchBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search Site" OnClick="btnSearch_click" /> 
<br /><br /> 
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="checkall" Text="Check All" OnClick="checkall_Click" /> 
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="uncheckall" Text="Uncheck All" OnClick="uncheckall_Click" />
```

Comment: Thanks gurus for the prompt response. @gilly3, et all, if I use codingbiz's solution, checkall and uncheckall are hidden and remain hidden even after clicking the Search site button. Same with codingbiz's code except that it works if I combine it with the if...conditional I showed above. I just would like to know if I am on the right track. Again, the way we would like it to work is the check/uncheck buttons to be invisible on page load but become visible after clicking search and stay visible until new page is loaded.

Comment: check it, you are doing something wrong. debug your code and put a break point in the btnSearch_Click.

Comment: @codingbiz, I am probably doing something wrong but a combination of this line:
<asp:Checkbox ID="checkall" Visible="False" ... /> and my if ...conditional appear to be working.

As usual to you experts on this great forum, I thank you ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Just Make the visibility none for it.

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="checkall" Text="Check All" OnClick="checkall_Click" style="display:none"/> 
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uncheckall" Text="Uncheck All" OnClick="uncheckall_Click" style="display:none"/>
```